# How to Draw Rectangle Chart Using Three Layers of Data?

Tags: legending, code-request, charts

I have some data given at three levels:

```
ClearAll[level1, level2, level3, labLevel1, labLevel2, 
    labLevel3];
level1 = {38.63, 16.17};
level2 = {{19.75, 9.26, 9.61}, {2, 6.07, 8.10}};
level3 = {{{5.88, 5.02, 5.56, 3.3}, {4.05, 2.21, 3}, {4.5, 4.91, 0.2}}, {{1, 1},{2.77, 3.3},{2.07, 1.5, 3.11, 1.43}}};
```

For labels across 3 levels:

```
labLevel1 = {"Distortions induced by State", 
"Barriers to domestic/foreign entry"};

labLevel2 = {{"Public ownership", "Involvelment in business operations", "Simplification/evaluation of regulations"}, {"Adm. burden on start-ups", "Barriers in services & network sectors", 
"Barriers to trade & investment"}};

 labLevel3 = {
 {{"Scope of SOEs", "Gov\[CloseCurlyQuote]t Involv. in network 
 sectors", "Direct control", "Governance of SOEs"}, {"Price 
 controls", "Command & control regulation", 
 "Public procurement"}, {"Assessment of impact on competition",
 "Interaction with interest groups", 
 "Complexity of regulatory procedures"}},
 {{"Adm. req. for LL com. & pers. owned enter.", 
 "Licenses & permits"}, {"Barriers in services sectors", 
 "Barriers in network sectors"}, {"Barriers to FDI", 
 "Tariff barriers", "Treatment of foreign suppliers", 
 "Barriers to trade facilitation"}}
 };
```

`level1` determines the `level1` size of a rectangular represented both as numbers and percentages. Since `level1` has two numbers, the rectangle will be first divided into two `parts` as percentages `38.63/total(level1)` and  `16.17/total(level1)`. Zooming into `level1` determines percentages at the `level2`. The zooming in at the `level3` will follow the same percentage calculation. For part 1, all the percentages will be calculated using `38.63` and for part 2, using `16.17`.

`part 1` and `part 2` should be constructed to allow for comparability. That is, all individual percentages in both parts should be calculated over `38.63+16.17`. Hence, `x %` in `part 1` should cover the same size as `x %` in `part 2`.

For illustrative purposes I attach the following picture showing the way for calculations and the division of the original rectangle.

[image]

Similar charts exist as pie charts but not as rectangular charts. In the repository, there is no chart in rectangular format.

Another example of the appearance of the rectangle chart is:

[image]

**EDIT**

From @Domen, I got this code from MMA:

```
ResourceFunction["TreemapPlot"][level3, 
"ColorFunction" -> (If[#3, ColorData[97][#. 
[[1]]], White] &), 
"Background" -> FaceForm[Opacity[1]]]
```

This correctly divides the rectangle but borders between the parts and sub-parts are not identified.

[image]

**EDIT 1**
see the following table for the dendrogram:

[image]

Comment: Do you know about the resource function [TreemapPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TreemapPlot/)?

Comment: @Domen: No, I did not know about it. I will look at it now. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please try using it, then edit the questio and include your code if you encounter any problems.

Comment: @Domen: I looked at it but none of them is similar to what I request here. In my question, given a rectangle, I want to create sub-compartments to represent the individual items. In my question, there is a tree structure, like dendrogram.

Comment: I did not read into details your question because it looks more complicated than it actually is. I believe a simple `ResourceFunction["TreemapPlot"][level3, "ColorFunction" -> (If[#3, ColorData[97][#[[1]]], White] &), "Background" -> FaceForm[Opacity[1]]]` is exactly what you are looking for (you may want to tweak the color function to your needs).

Comment: @Domen: Yes, I will now give some codes, which divides the rectangle correctly but the coloring and border between parts are not specified.

Comment: @Domen: Your code works fine at the Part level but the bordering between `sublists` are not shown. These bordering are critical for my purpose. I should be able to see the compartments within each part.

Comment: "This correctly divides the rectangle but borders between the parts and sub-parts are not identified." -- I think `MosaicPlot` can be used then, but this would require the data to be re-interpeted.

Comment: Is there any logical (or problem area) dependence between the names/variables of the different levels?

Comment: @Anton Antonov: Does MMA have `MosaicPlot`? I searched for it but no success

Comment: Here is a link to the paclet ["MosaicPlot"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/MosaicPlot/). I will post an extended comment how it *might* be applied to data.

Comment: @Anton Antonov: yes, please see the edit with a table showing the structure of the table and dependency between the variables in `gray` areas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148797/discussion-between-tugrul-temel-and-anton-antonov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate levels using the option `"Spacing"`and associate colors with different levels using the option `"ColorFunction"`.

In the following example, we assign colors `Red` and `Cyan` to the initial level, and `ColorData[7]` to the second level and, for the leaf nodes we blend `White` with parent node's color using rescaled node values as weights.

```
treeMapPlot = ResourceFunction["TreemapPlot"];

colorRules = Join[{{1} -> Red, {2} -> Cyan}, 
  Thread[# -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ #])] & @
   Tuples[Range @ Dimensions @ level3]]
```

[image]

```
CF = Switch[Length @ #, 
   0, White, 
   1 | 2, Lighter@Lighter[ # /. colorRules], 
   3, Blend[{White, Take[#, 2] /. colorRules}, 
       Rescale[#2, MinMax @ level3[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]], {.3, 1}]]] &; 

tmp = treeMapPlot[level3,
  "Spacing" -> .2,  
  "ColorFunction" -> CF, 
  "Background" -> FaceForm[Opacity[1]],
  "FrameStyle" -> EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, White]]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, `treeMapPlot` does not have an option to specify labels.

One way to add labels is to post-process the output to inject labels:

```
indices = DeleteCases[Sort@PadRight@Position[level3, _, Heads->False], 0, All];

legendcolors = CF @@@ Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, level3, {3}], 2];

legendlabels = Flatten[MapIndexed[Row[{Row@#2, #}, Spacer[10]] &, 
  Map[StringReplace[ #, "\n" -> " "] &, labLevel3, {-1}], {3}], 2];

legend =  SwatchLegend[legendcolors, legendlabels, 
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Alignment -> Left, 
    Dividers -> {False, 
     Thread[1 + Accumulate@Flatten[Map[Length] /@ level3] -> True]}]&),
   LegendMarkerSize -> 15];

ii = 0;

Legended[tmp /. Inset[_, pos_, {Center, Center}] :> 
    Inset[Style[(Map[Row]@indices)[[++ii]], 12], pos, {Center, Center}], 
 Placed[legend, Right]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice... Can we put the `level` numbers inside each rectangle and add rectangle labels using swatch format? The label names are given in the question.

Comment: @Tugrul Bey, please see the updated versionl.

Comment: Bey: Thanks for your patience! and excellent code.

Answer (score 2):

### Second comment

Does the following dataset correspond to relationships in data?

If yes, can you provide the *correct* dataset representation?

(It is likely the one I produced below is wrong...)

```mathematica
res12 = MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {labLevel1, labLevel2}];
pos = Position[res12, _String];
res3 = MapThread[Rule, {labLevel3, level3}, 2] /. HoldPattern[x_ -> y_] :> Thread[x -> y];
recs = Map[Append[res12[[Sequence @@ Most[#]]], res3[[Sequence @@ #]]] &, pos];
recs2 = Map[Flatten, recs /. HoldPattern[x_Rule] :> (List @@ x)];
dsRecords = 
 Dataset[recs2][All, 
   AssociationThread[{"First", "Second", "Third", "Value"}, #] &] /. x_String :> StringReplace[x, (WhitespaceCharacter ..) -> " "]
```

[image]

### First comment

*(Not an answer, extended comment.)*
*(If this is of interest I will add comments later today.)*

```mathematica
PacletInstall["AntonAntonov/MosaicPlot"];
Needs["AntonAntonov`MosaicPlot`"];
lsLevel1 = (Prepend[List @@ #1, "1"] &) /@ MapThread[Rule, {labLevel1, level1}];
lsLevel12 = (Prepend[List @@ #1, "2"] &) /@ Flatten[MapThread[Rule, {labLevel2, level2}, 2]];
res3 = MapThread[Rule, {labLevel3, level3}, 2] /. HoldPattern[x_ -> y_] :> Thread[x -> y];
lsLevel13 = (Prepend[List @@ #1, "3"] &) /@ Flatten[res3];
lsArr = Join[lsLevel1, lsLevel12, lsLevel13];
MosaicPlot[lsArr, "ExpandLastColumn" -> True, "LabelRotation" -> {{1, 0.2}, {0, 1}}, "ZeroProbability" -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. Your code does not really fit into what I am after. I simply want to represent three layers (connected to each other) in a rectangle so as to compare all three layers at the same time by just looking at the chart.

Comment: Please, see my update.

Comment: Unfortunately, your data set has missing `level3` elements. For example, in level2, `public ownership` has 4 sub-items; while `level2` `involvement in business` has 3 sub-items. In your dataset, all of them have 2 sub-items. The structure is precisely given in the table I sent earlier. Just see each column with a varying number of sub-items.

Comment: In EDIT 1, I gave the dendrogram for the levels and variables.

Comment: Is [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ALgP.png) of the table you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is the image I refer to.

Comment: In the code above, the levels and variables for each level are correctly given. `labLevel1` has 2 variables; `labLevel2` has 6 variables; and for each of these 6 variables, there is a group of variables given as `level3`.